# Netbeans-Glassfish: Preserve Session Across Redeployment failed

Tags: java, session, netbeans, glassfish

My java web app has session checking. Every time I save, it redeploys. I've already checked the option in netbeans "Preserve Session Across Redeployment" but when i looked the logged. I have this error

```
Info: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) for context '/webapp'
Info: Running on PrimeFaces 3.4.2
Severe: PWC2768: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2553)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1296)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946) ...
```

and further down the log

```
Warning: WEB0517: Unable to restore sessions for web module [/webapp] from previous deployment
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2553)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1296)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
```

so every time I save java files, I need to login again.

How can I solve this. Thanks